# django queryset "contains" for lists, not strings

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to search a queryset of paragraphs that has a many-to-many field mapping each paragraph to a chapter. Every chapter is part of a book, each of which has multiple authors, and each author can have multiple books and hence paragraphs. I want to exclude a particular author from the returned queryset of paragraphs.

simplified models:

```
class Paragraph(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, related_name = 'paragraphs')

class Chapter(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name = 'chapters')

class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'books')
```

First I tried:

```
paragraphs.exclude(chapter__book__authors__contains = author)
```

This doesn't work because *author* is an object, not a string. I can do this manually in Python with:

```
[p for p in paragraphs if author not in p.chapter.book.authors.filter()]
```

But this is much slower than the QuerySet way. What I really want to say is:

```
paragraphs.exclude(author__in = chapter__book__authors)
```

However, this doesn't work because "author" is a separately queried object that I can't get to from, so it's not valid Django. How can I express this, keeping the objects as actual objects rather than strings?

**EDIT**

If I run

```
paragraphs.exclude(chapter__book__authors__id = author.id)
```

it almost works, but still includes results where a book has multiple authors and one of the authors is the one I want to ignore.

Comment: Can you add your models?

Comment: The line in your edit doesn't need the id (it could be `paragraphs.exclude(chapter__book__authors=author)`). That doesn't change the result, and it seemed to work in a quick test, but maybe I did something wrong. Can you show a minimal example of a combination of paragraphs, chapters, books and authors where this fails?

Answer (score 0):

If `author` is an object you should be able to achieve what you want by passing in a field of the `author` object.

For example

```
paragraphs.exclude(chapter__book__authors__contains=author.name)
```

Comment: I don't think this would work since it'd have to compare an author object (or it's id) to name. ```paragraphs.exclude(chapter__book__authors__id=author.id)``` should work.

Comment: As schillingt pointed out, this raises an error 'Related field has invalid lookup: contains' as each author is an object. @schillingt your comment seems like it should work, but it's not filtering anything when I try it.